# Why Can't I Assign Values with For-Each Loops? Java

Tags: java

I was trying to rewrite an exercise in my book using for-each loops but it does not work... My understanding is that the loop executes statements to every element of the array in ascending order from index 0. Why does this not work?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

//Fill array with inputs
int[] numbers = new int[10];
System.out.print("Enter 10 integers: ");
for (int u : numbers) {
    u = input.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`u` only holds a copy of the current element. It's assignment won't be reflected on the iterated array.

Comment: Ah understood! So u is only a copy and doesn't refer at all to the array referenced right?

Answer (score 0):

For changing the value in foreach you should use iterator. But you can use a simple for as you know the size of the array.

```
For(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
       Array[i]=<what you want>;
  }
```